# Maven project integration with Jenkins #selenium scripts

Tags: java, maven, selenium, jenkins

I am trying to run selenium scripts on Jenkins locally on my computer. I was using eclipse project and then i converted it to Maven by configure>convert to maven project. My Jenkins configuration is [image: Jenkins1![Jenkins2]

[image: Jenkins2]

Look at the configuration in the images. This is what I have done so far. I am a beginner to all this so don't know what I am missing. My console output on Jenkins is [image: Jenkins output]

Comment: Should i change my file name to .pom? Or I need to change my scripts? Because my script still says "Firefox.com" to localhost, Jenkins?

Comment: Is it possible to rename the directory to a Name without blank?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
/user/Gauravgandhi/Documents/workspace/Applico/Website
```

for file system path and just pass `pom.xml` under Root Pom text box and define goals for the same.
I am hoping you configure JDK and Maven at jenkins level under configure jenkins link.

Please let me know if it works or not.

Comment: i did this but it still says no "pom.xml". How to configure JDK and maven at jenkins level?

Comment: i did configured JDk and maven..but i am still seeing this output Started by user anonymous
Building in workspace /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/maven
FSSCM.checkout /Users/Gauravgandhi/Documents/workspace/Applico to /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/maven
FATAL: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Parameter 'directory' is not a directory
 at hudson.FilePath.act(FilePath.java:920)
 at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1706)
 at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:231)

Answer (score 0):

Gaurav,

Please make the setup using admin user in your machine or give full permission to your current user at every level.

Comment: i am running it using admin account